# Convert a decimal number to its corresponding binary @Love babbar

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why is this code not giving proper answer for odd numbers but it is giving right answers for even numnbers.

```
 **int main(){
  int n;
  cin>> n;

  int ans = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while(n != 0){
    int bit = n & 1;
    ans = (bit * pow(10, i)) + ans;
    n = n >> 1;
    i++;
  }
  cout<<ans;
}**
```

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Be specific about your question. It's unlikely that someone would explain the program line by line for you.

Comment: ans = (bit * pow(10, i)) + ans; this part

Comment: Using pow in integer mathematics is not recommended it is a floating point function. Just  keep a pow variable that you multiply (or shift) each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Change `pow(10, i)` to `pow(2, i)`, since binary works in powers of 2, not powers of 10. Also (side note), you can change the `while` loop to a `for` loop concerning incrementing `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; n != 0; i++)
{
    //convert n to binary
}
```

Comment: Also, don't use `pow(2, i)`; it returns a **floating-point** value, not an integer. It's simple (not to mention faster) to generate that value yourself: `int exp = 1;` and each time through the loop, `exp *= 2;`.